# How to inclease the cache capacity of my app?

Tags: android, webview, browser-cache

I am developing webview app on android studio.

The problem is that my app does not cache more than 20.0MB.
I checked it from **Settings>ApplicationManager>MyWebviewApp>Cache**.
When the cache reaches over 20.0MB, the old cache seems to be deleted.

Could I increase the cache capacity?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this to overcome your problem. [Source](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?class=android.webkit.WebSettings&method=setAppCachePath)

```
WebView wvSubscribeNow  = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.your_wv);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        //noinspection deprecation
        wvSubscribeNow.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    }
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        //noinspection deprecation
        wvSubscribeNow.getSettings().setEnableSmoothTransition(true);
    }
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        wvSubscribeNow.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(true);
    }
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        wvSubscribeNow.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE);
    }
    wvSubscribeNow.getSettings().setAppCachePath(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());
    wvSubscribeNow.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    wvSubscribeNow.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    wvSubscribeNow.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wvSubscribeNow.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the method `setAppCacheMaxSize` was deprecated in API Level 18...?

Comment: I tried but it did not work... cache still seems to be limited 20.0MB.

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope it work.

```
WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.vWeb);
view.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
view.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024 * 1024 * 10);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It has been deprecated in API Level 18... Is there any alternative method..?